# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el email de mi cuenta en Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, login

Me gustaria poder iniciar sesión con un correo electronico nuevo que tengo. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el email de mi cuenta aquí en Stack Overflow?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Para cambiar el correo electrónico

- Ve a tu perfil → edición de perfil y configuración → editar perfil ([acceso directo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/currentuser)).
- Cambia tu correo electrónico en la sección *Información privada*, que se encuentra debajo del todo.

#### Para añadir inicios de sesión

- Ve a tu perfil → edición de perfil y configuración → mis inicios de sesión ([acceso directo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/currentuser)).
- Allí, selecciona *añadir más inicios de sesión*.

Comment: El correo antiguo sigue mostrandose en inicios de sesion, por qué?. Solo quisiera tener 1 solo email para iniciar sesion, nada mas.

Comment: @RobertGomez porque añadiste una sesión. Si quieres eliminarlo, selecciona _quitar_ al lado de esa dirección.

Comment: a ver si me explico, no he agregado ningun inicio de sesion adicional. Solamente cambié el email usando el enlace que me has proporcionado, luego de esto, fui a inicios de sesion para ver simplemente, y veo uno creado con mi email antiguo, al borrarlo me dice que no puedo eliminar la unica opcion de iniciar sesion que tengo. No quisiera tener el email antiguo en mi cuenta, solo quiero dejar el nuevo, que por cierto, no me funciona para iniciar sesion, debo ingresar con el antiguo, incluso después de haberlo cambiado.

Comment: @RobertGomez ¿has seguido los pasos de _añadir inicios de sesión_? Si solamente te sale uno -el antiguo- es porque aún no añadiste el nuevo.

Comment: en inicios de sesion, que debo elegir?, no quiero crear otra cuenta mas de openid, estoy confundido. Debo elegir Google, o que debo hacer?.

Comment: @RobertGomez si tu nueva cuenta es de gmail, selecciona Google. Si no, puedes añadir Facebook, Yahoo, LiveJournal, Blogger o AOL.